# Iterate through functions calls in various files

Tags: search, tags, filetype-c

I can jump to a function definition thanks to `:tjump`.

Or I can search for a function call in a file with `/` but is there a way
to iterate through function calls across various files ?

If the solution is language specific, I am interested in how to do it for C.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I replaced references by calls. Is there anything else that's unclear ? 
Seems like your comment could make an answer. Do you want to make it an answer or should I do it ?

Comment: I’m happy to let your answer stand :) “iterate” was really the word I was struggling with, but at this point I’ll delete my comments. You might be especially interested in `:help :cdo` and `:help Cfilter`

Answer (score 3):

It seems that `:grep some_word` is what I was looking for. It populates a quickfix list that you can navigate with `:cnext` and `:cprev`.

A good idea is to map those to `]q` and `[q` respectively.

`:cfirst` and `:clast` might be worth mentionning too.